# Read CSV file and create directory in PowerShell script

Tags: bash, powershell, csv

I want to create a directory(File or Folder) reading Csv file in a given path
Example as below.

```
Type    Path
Folder  C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Test\
File    C:\User\PC\Desktop\example.txt
```

I want shell script to create a file or folder. I don't know where to go for.
Please help me. I am new to shell scripting.

Comment: Please read a Powershell tutorial. As of now, the question [isn't really suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to SO. It's basically a "please, give me a complete solution" - which is frowned upon.

Comment: can you suggest me some tutorials

Comment: Try Microsoft's [Virtual Academy](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-microsoft-powershell-8276?l=r54IrOWy_2304984382), [Ted Dawson's](https://programminghistorian.org/lessons/intro-to-powershell) and [SqlserverCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/PowerShell/72051/) for some starting points.

Answer (score -1):

You should start by defining your root, say "c:\users\pc\desktop\"

Next,Traverse through each line of your CSV.

```
csV_line: C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Testfolder1\testfolder2
```

replace the root by **''** so all that's left is Testfolder1\testfolder2

You can then split them on **\**

```
Result:    Testfolder1 AND testfolder2
```

Check with a regex or -like '*.*' to see **if** it has an extension.

Depending on the result you would use **new-item -type directory** or **file**.

Comment: Your answer is all over the place and doesn't read very well. Maybe adding some formatting to distinguish code from explanation might help, but I think it needs re-writing to be properly understandable.

Comment: I did some reformatting, all the ingredients are there for her to tackle this issue.